# Horizontally align img & text?

Tags: css, positioning

Taking baby steps with web development.  I have an application that has a loader screen very similar to [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jakc/z3zpz/).

On a Desktop browser it looks acceptable with the text/image vertically and horizontally centered (to the eye anyhow).

However, when you view my application on smaller screen sizes, the text/image begin to not align horizontally to the center of the screen.

I have been reading many related posts and blogs but have been unable to get my text/image to stay centered, regardless of device width. This can be replicated by resizing the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jakc/z3zpz/) preview to make it thinner.

```
<div id="preloader">
<div class="preloaderContent">
    <div id="loadLabel">Please Wait</div>
    <img src="http://www.igfa.org/images/throbber.gif"><br>
    </div>
</div>

#preloader {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:#3399FF;
    z-index:999;
}

.preloaderContent {
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    top: 40%;
}

.preloaderContent img {
    display : block;
    margin : auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#loadLabel {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI',Helvetica,Arial,'Sans-Serif';
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

Apologies it is a bit of a mess.  Can someone point out the error(s) in my ways?

Comment: try to add a margin-top in %

Comment: you can add % margins, but i would suggest you work on the answer i provided below to be perfectly sure.

Answer (score 1):

You want to put in something like this:

```
.preloaderContent {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -50px;/*half of height*/
    margin-left: -100px;/*half of width*/
}
```

The negative margins mean that the center of the div is in the center rather than the top left corner. This will resize according to browser window size.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/z3zpz/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some responsive css.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }


/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }


/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

By adding specific css to the above media queries, you can modify the layout per the device. Don't forget to put the above media queries below your css ( to be on the safe side).

Hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in 50% and 50% and add to this negative margin of about half content size.

jsfiddle.net/z3zpz/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

html, body { height: 100%; }

body { position: relative; background: #3399FF; }

#preloader { display: table; width: 100%; height: 100%; }

.preloaderContent { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; }

.preloaderContent img { display : block; margin: 0 auto; }

#loadLabel { padding-bottom: 10px; font-size: 30px; font-weight: 300; font-family: 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, 'Sans-Serif'; color: #FFFFFF; }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this one if height and width of content(.preloaderContent) is known.

```
html, body { height: 100%; }

#preloader {position: relative; background: #3399FF; width: 100%; height: 100%; }

.preloaderContent { position:absolute; height:100px; width:160px; top:50%; left:50%; margin-top:-50px; margin-left:-80px; }
```